# Is it possible to join a column from Table B to Table A without creating a new table C in Hive SQL?

Tags: join, hive

I'm working with very large tables in Hive so I'd like to avoid having to create a whole new table when joining a single column from Table 2 to Table 1.

My first pass using the INSERT and UPDATE statements with the following test data didn't work.

Is there a way to do this or is it simpler to just create Table 3 by joining Table 1 to Table 2 and then dropping Table 1?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_1;
CREATE TABLE table_1 (id VARCHAR(64), cost INT, diag_cd VARCHAR(64));
INSERT INTO TABLE table_1
  VALUES ('A0001', 1000, 'A1'), ('A0001', 2000, 'B1'), ('A0001', 3000, 'B1'), 
  ('B0001', 5000, 'A1'), ('B0001', 10000, 'B1'), ('B0001', 15000, 'C1'),
  ('C0001', 11000, 'B1'), ('C0001', 14000, 'C1'), ('C0001', 20000, 'C1');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_2;
CREATE TABLE table_2 (id VARCHAR(64), prodt_cd VARCHAR(64));
INSERT INTO TABLE table_2
  VALUES ('A0001', 'OAP'), ('B0001', 'OAPIN'), ('C0001', 'MOAPIN');

INSERT INTO TABLE table_1 prodt_cd VARCHAR(64);
UPDATE table_1 t1 SET t1.prodt_cd = t2.prodt_cd
INNER JOIN table_2 t2 
ON t1.id = t2.id;
```

Comment: Do you get an error with this test? The last insert looks wrong. To add a column use `ALTER TABLE table_1 ADD COLUMNS (prodt_cd  VARCHAR(64));`

Comment: @Mike67 Thanks - I changed the INSERT statement to the ALTER TABLE statement which runs fine, but when I run the following 3 lines I get the error: "Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 29:126 extraneous input 't1' expecting SET near 't1' in update statement line 1:52 mismatched input '.' expecting = near 't1' in update statement".

Comment: Found similar questions online - looks like Hive doesn't support column updates in this way?

Comment: May be just syntax issue. Try this: `UPDATE t1 SET t1.prodt_cd = t2.prodt_cd FROM table_1 t1 INNER JOIN table_2 t2  ON t1.id = t2.id;`

Comment: @Mike67 I'm getting "Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 34:6 mismatched input '.' expecting = near 't1' in update statement". Did it work for you?

Comment: Hive has special syntax. Try this: `UPDATE table_1 t1 SET prodt_cd = t2.prodt_cd FROM table_2 t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.id;`

Comment: Yea I'm still getting this error: "Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 39:60 extraneous input 't1' expecting SET near 'prodt_cd' line 3:0 missing EOF at 'FROM' near 'prodt_cd'". I've fiddled around with excluding or including the `t1`s but doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry - My mistake. Hive only supports merge. Try this: `MERGE INTO table_1 t1 USING table_2 t2 ON t1.id=t2.id WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET prodt_cd=t2.prodt_cd;`

Comment: Thanks Mike - this should work but looks like the version of Hive we're using in my company doesn't support MERGE. Drat

Comment: @Mike67 Thanks for your help - just found an alternative fix & posted below.

Answer (score 0):

After some research and help from Mike67 I found a solution.

It appears Hive does not support COLUMN UPDATE or MERGE statements, but a simple alternative is to create an empty table and then populate it with fields from a join:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_3; 
CREATE TABLE table_3 LIKE table_1; 

INSERT INTO TABLE table_3 
SELECT a.*, b.prodt_cd
FROM table_1 AS a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_2 AS b 
ON a.id = b.id;
```